# Project Referencing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to reference a single project from two different projects in VS 2012. Example: both 1 and 2 are referencing 3. This despite not being a circular dependency, is still not working for me. Project 1 gives the error "The type or namespace could not be found", whereas project 2 can successfully reference project 3. I need this kind of setup because of my architecture and can't reference 1 and 2 directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the .Net framework for project 1 from Version-4 to Version-4.5 did the trick for me.
This is the answer to my question. stackoverflow.com/a/6090384/1099142

Answer (score 0):

As example, that third project is class library. You should be able to reference it from project1 and project2. Maybe close visual studio, clean, rebuild it and also check if project1 or project2 is not referencing each other. Try to delete those references and add again: class library reference to project1 and then to project2.